# Can XPages FilteringSelect Control be Tweaked to Allow Multiple Selections from its Drop-down List?

Tags: xpages

On my XPage, I am using a FilteringSelect control from the XPages Extension Library and it works fine, if you are making just one selection from the drop-down list. (BTW, I am using Notes R9.0.1 and version 16 of the Extension Library.)

My question is this: Can my FilteringSelect control be tweaked to allow *multiple*  selections from its drop-down list? Any feedback will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if version 16 of the Extension Library has the Bootstrap4Xpages plugin, but if it does, you could use the select2 control.  Add a core list box control and make sure to set it to accept multiple values.  The select2 control will do the rest for you.

**UPDATE**

Since it's not part of the Extension Library, you can download the [Bootstrap4XPages plugin](https://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Bootstrap4XPages/releases/36F358E5C8DE52E786257D1E002BE42A), and install it on the server, from OpenNTF.  If you install it on the server and in your Domino Designer, you'll be able to use the < bx:select2PickerCombo >, control and connect it to your list box.  In the list box, make the "multiple" variable as true.  This way, users can type ahead to find the items in the list box, and be able to choose more than one.

Comment: Select2 is not in the Extension Library. You can add it by using the Bootstrap4XPages project or add it yourself. See Johnny Oldenburger's blog for more info... https://xpagesandmore.blogspot.com/2015/06/migrating-to-select2-version-400.html

Comment: Yes. Select2 sounds like the best solution in this case. I appreciate the feedback. Thanks much.